# self.property to nil vs [ivar release] case close

Tags: objective-c

There have been a lot of discussions on why you should not use setter in dealloc like you do in viewDidUnload.  Question is, why not just use [property release] in both dealloc or viewDidUnload? Doesn't that end the discussion or is there a reason why one should do self.property = nil in viewDidUnload instead?

That is, we always follow this idiom for everything - rather than using one form in viewDidUnload and another in dealloc, which seems senseless.

```
[ivar release];
ivar = nil;
```

Comment: Purists insist on this and that, but the main thing is to pick a scheme that makes sense to you and use it consistently (at least within a given app) so that you don't confuse yourself.  I personally favor using `self.propname = nil;` everywhere, even in `dealloc`.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is that nothing will happen with an object after dealloc, so you can just release property and don't worry about it being invalid pointer. On the other hand, if you do [property release] in viewDidUnload and not set it to nil, it will contain invalid pointer and this may lead to crash if property is used before new valid value assigned to it.

Comment: I mean we will always follow [ivar release] and ivar = nil; as a practice.  Setting ivar to nil is a good practice regardless of where you release it.

Comment: So why not use the selv.ivar = nil? It's the exact same thing, but shorter.

Comment: self.property = ... also does things like comparison and locking (unless declared as nonatomic). I prefer to avoid unneeded code so I use simply [property release] in dealloc. While in viewDidUnload in some cases it may be safer to use self.property=nil than [prop release] and prop=nil.

Comment: @fbernardo - Because self.ivar can potentially have issue that other SO posts have brought up - such as KVO and other side effects.

Comment: @Boon yes I pointed out locking in my answer, and totally forgot KVO, guess I don't use it that much :)

Answer (score 0):

Properties are save for this, you can set nil them everywhere, because them save releasing (setters are looking like `-(void)setProp { [prop release]; self.prop = nil; }`).
But if you use `[something release]`, you should do it in `viewDidUnload` method, because view can be unloaded, but controller not deallocated, which means possible memory leak in `viewDidLoad`. And if you call `[something release]` twice, it will cause crash for wrong counter decrease

Comment: Not if you always set your ivar to nil, you will never over release.

Answer (score 0):

All the other responses consider the two ways the same. But consider when you have an atomic property. It's a **lot** shorter and cleaner than the "pure" way.